# Get rid of login page after authenticate on auth server on ABP framework

Tags: c#, angular, abp

I'm working on ABP framework version 7+ using OpenIddict as auth server with Angular UI.

Well, when I try to log in at my auth url:

```
https://localhost:44331/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnec.....
```

[image]

The auth got successful, but I got redirected to a web login page as the following image:

[image]

Url of this site:

```
http://localhost:4200/?iss=https:%2F%2Flocalhost:44331%2F
```

So I need to click on that button, and after that, it redirects me to my home page:

```
http://localhost:4200/?iss=https:%2F%2Flocalhost:44331%2F
```

Also, after being redirected to the home page, if I try to manually use just  `http://localhost:4200`, it shows my home page (as I want).

I want to bypass or get rid of that login page with the Login button, and log me in to my home page; how can I do that?

I have a custom login model for Auth Server project:

```
public class CustomLoginModel : LoginModel
    {

        public CustomLoginModel(
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider,
            IOptions<Volo.Abp.Account.Web.AbpAccountOptions> accountOptions,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> identityOptions)
        : base(schemeProvider, accountOptions, identityOptions)
        {
            LocalizationResourceType = typeof(MyResource);
        }

        public override async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string action)
        {
            await CheckLocalLoginAsync();

            ValidateModel();

            ExternalProviders = await GetExternalProviders();

            EnableLocalLogin = await SettingProvider.IsTrueAsync(AccountSettingNames.EnableLocalLogin);

            await ReplaceEmailToUsernameOfInputIfNeeds();

            await IdentityOptions.SetAsync();

            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
                LoginInput.UserNameOrEmailAddress,
                LoginInput.Password,
                LoginInput.RememberMe,
                true
            );

            await IdentitySecurityLogManager.SaveAsync(new IdentitySecurityLogContext()
            {
                Identity = IdentitySecurityLogIdentityConsts.Identity,
                Action = result.ToIdentitySecurityLogAction(),
                UserName = LoginInput.UserNameOrEmailAddress
            });

            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return await TwoFactorLoginResultAsync();
            }

            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(LoginInput.UserNameOrEmailAddress) ??
                       await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(LoginInput.UserNameOrEmailAddress);

            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                Alerts.Warning(L["UserLockedOutMessage"]);
                return Page();
            }

            if (result.IsNotAllowed)
            {
                Alerts.Warning(L["LoginIsNotAllowed"]);
                return Page();
            }

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (user == null || user.AccessFailedCount == 1)
                {
                    Alerts.Danger(L["LoginFailureFirstAttempt"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (user.AccessFailedCount == 2)
                    {
                        Alerts.Danger(L["LoginFailureSecondAttempt"]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Alerts.Danger(L["LoginFailureThirdAttempt"]);
                    }
                }
                return Page();
            }

            Debug.Assert(user != null, nameof(user) + " != null");

            return RedirectSafely(ReturnUrl, ReturnUrlHash);
        }
    }
```

The line which redirect to that page is `return RedirectSafely(ReturnUrl, ReturnUrlHash);`

That ReturnUrl comes from the original Abp LoginModel:

```
public class LoginModel : AccountPageModel
{
    [HiddenInput]
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string ReturnUrlHash { get; set; }
    ...
  }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you describe your main goal please ? You are described "I am using angular" but I saw the custom login page with Razor. You are described at question "using angular". When you are using resource owner flow, you can login in angular app. So you can customise the component.

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Authorization